# Comparing values using maps

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community

There is One Account to Many Opportunities. There is Amount field in Opportunity. I am trying to find Opportunity with Minimum Amount against **`Account Id`**. I need a map like this **`Map<Accid,Opportunity> Opptoupdate;`**

I tried this way but I am not sure how to proceed as you can see I am comparing amount but I need to put this in above map(**`Map<Accid,Opportunity> Opptoupdate;`**) with minimum amount opp.

```
opportunity temp = new opportunity();
map < id, list < Opportunity >> mapwithoppList = new map < id, list < Opportunity >> ();
list < Account > AccList = new list < Account > ([Select id, Name, (Select id, Amount from opportunities) from Account where name = 'GenePoint']);
for (Account a: AccList) {
    if (a.opportunities.size() > 0) {
        mapwithoppList.put(a.id, a.opportunities);
    }
    for (ID st: mapwithoppList.keyset()) {
        temp = new opportunity();
        for (Opportunity op: mapwithoppList.get(st)) {
            temp.Amount = op.Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can obtain minimums in a single [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) call.

Comment: Keith thanks for response ...but I want in the format of Map<Accid,Opportunity> Opptoupdate;

Comment: Check this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5740/get-compare-children-values-on-map

Comment: Saroj I checked that link but I have to something like this at end of second for loop Opportunity temp = mapwithoppList .get(st.id).[0].Name; and after this I need this opp to put against acc id in this was Map<Accid,Opportunity> Opptoupdate;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list < Account > AccList = new list < Account > ([Select id, Name, (Select id, Amount from opportunities) from Account where name = 'GenePoint']);
Map<Accid,Opportunity> Opptoupdate = new Map<Accid,Opportunity>();

for( Account account : AccList) {
    for(Opportunity opportunity : account.opportunities) {
        if(opportunity.Amount == null || Opptoupdate.get(opportunity.AccountId).Amount > opportunity.Amount) {
            Opptoupdate.put(opportunity.AccountId, opportunity);
        }

    }
}
```

Check if this work for you

Comment: I am getting this error "Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Opportunity, Decimal
"

Comment: I tried this in developer console

Comment: Check now, I have updated the code